# Lebesgue Measure of an interval (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am following the book "Measure and Integration" by Leonard F. Richardson. In this book he develops the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ by :

1. Taking $X_n = [-N,N)$ and defining the measure on the field of elementary sets (by $\mu[a,b)= b-a$ ) and then using Hopf Extension theorem to extend this measure on the sigma algebra of Lebesgue Measurable sets of $X_N$.
2. Now using the $\sigma-$ finiteness of $\mathbb{R}$, we define Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ by

$$l(A) = \sum l(A \cap S_N)$$ where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , $S_N= X_N - X_{N-1}$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Using this definition of measure of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, how do we conclude that the measure of an open interval $(a,b)$ is $b-a$ ?

Please help.

Comment: Hint: $[a,b) = [a,a] \cup (a,b)$.

Comment: @mrp the way measure is defined, I think its easy to show that the measure of a singleton is 0. Because the outer measure of a singleton {a} is the infimum of all measures of the elementary sets of the type [a,a+$\epsilon)$. Now to show the measure of $[a,b)$ is $b-a$, we again have to take the intersection in $S_N$'s and do the summation over all such $N$'s where the intersection is non empty. This step of computation is where I am getting stuck ! Thanks in advance